# File upload control reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular

### Issue

I currently have a form that has a bunch of fields, one of them being a file upload field. They all form part of a `FormGroup` that is declared in my constructor. Now all the text controls I am able to access by using `this.control.value` except my file control. When I try to access the `value` of the form control for the file all I get is `C:/fakepath/image.png`.

Is there a way to access the actual file data so that I can upload it to my API?

---

### Code

My `FormControl` declarations:

```
/**
 * Category of the product
 */
public category = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required
]);

/**
 * Name of the product
 */
public name = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(3)
]);

/**
 * Description of the product
 */
public description = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required
]);

/**
 * Price of the product
 */
public price = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required
]);

/**
 * Image of the product
 */
public image = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required
]);
```

My constructor for the page/component:

```
constructor(private api: ApiService,
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.productForm = formBuilder.group({
      category: this.category,
      name: this.name,
      description: this.description,
      price: this.price,
      image: this.image
    });
}
```

How I am currently trying to access the file

```
public async createProduct(): Promise<any> {
  console.log(this.image.value);
}
```

Comment: Angular doesn't support files in its forms. You will have to set it by hand (as far as I know, of course)

Comment: you can serialize `this.productForm` and add it into the FormData as a property and add the image as a seperate property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1: HTML Template (file-upload.component.html)**

Define simple input tag of type file. Add a function to (change)-event for handling choosing files.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file"
           id="file"
           (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

**Step 2: Upload Handling in TypeScript (in component file)**

Define an default variable for selected file.

```
fileToUpload: File = null;
```

Create function which you use in (change)-event of your file input tag:

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
}
```

**Step 3: File-Upload Service**

By uploading a file via POST-method you should use FormData, because so you can add file to http request.

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<boolean> {
    const endpoint = 'your-destination-url';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    // Append image file to formdata as a seperate property
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

    // Append reactive form data too in a seperate property
    formData.append('productForm', JSON.stringify(this.productForm, null, 4));
    return this.httpClient
      .post(endpoint, formData, { headers: yourHeadersConfig })
      .map(() => { return true; })
      .catch((e) => this.handleError(e));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to access the actual file data so that I can upload it to my API?

You can access it in that way:

```
// template
<input
 type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)"
>

// component
onFileChanged(event) {
  // this.image will be updated each time the file
  // in input will be changed
  this.image = event.target.files[0];
  console.log(this.image);
}


createProduct(): Promise<Product> {
  console.log(this.image);
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(
    'image',
    this.image
  );

  // add other fields to formData:
  formData.append("name", this.productForm.controls['name'].value);

  formData.append("description", this.productForm.controls['description'].value);

  const url = 'urlToApi';

  return this.http.post(url, formData)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```